# CDI in Google App Engine reinstantiates injected managed beans, losing JSF beans' current data

Tags: google-app-engine, jsf-2, cdi, jpa-2.0

I've managed to set up JSF 2.2 with Oracle's Mojarra, CDI 1.0 with Google Guice 3.0 and JPA 2.0 with DataNucleus 3.1.3 (I omitted the JPA part in the code I'm posting here) to make it run on Google App Engine (SDK 1.9.48), except for a BIG drawback: when I try to `@Inject` a `@javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean`, a bean instance is properly injected, yet it's destroyed when the execution code ends, losing all the data previously modified in the injected instance. This makes the CDI implementation incomplete, because JSF beans can't "interact" at all.

This is my implementation:

1. Web.xml

   ```
           <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
           <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
               xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
               <display-name>MyApp</display-name>

               <description>CDI, JSF 2.2 and JPA example</description>

               <!-- ***** Designate client-side state saving, since GAE doesn't handle 
                   server side (JSF default) state management. ***** -->
               <context-param>
                   <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
                   <param-value>client</param-value>
               </context-param>

               <!-- Set the default suffix for JSF pages to .xhtml -->
               <context-param>
                   <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
                   <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
               </context-param>

               <!-- Disable use of threading for single-threaded environments such as the 
                   Google AppEngine. -->
               <context-param>
                   <description>
                            When enabled, the runtime initialization and default ResourceHandler 
                            implementation will use threads to perform their functions. Set this 
                            value to false if threads aren't desired (as in the case of running
                            within the Google Application Engine).
                            Note that when this option is disabled, the ResourceHandler will not 
                            pick up new versions of resources when ProjectStage is development.
                       </description>
                   <param-name>com.sun.faces.enableThreading</param-name>
                   <param-value>false</param-value>
               </context-param>

               <!-- allow dependency-injection into ManagedBeans -->
               <context-param>
                   <param-name>com.sun.faces.injectionProvider</param-name>
                   <param-value>cdi.InjectionProvider</param-value>
               </context-param>

               <!-- ***** Specify JBoss Expression Language Over Default -->
               <context-param>
                   <param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
                   <param-value>org.jboss.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>
               </context-param>

               <!-- ***** Load the JavaServer Faces Servlet ***** -->
               <servlet>
                   <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
                   <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
                   <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
               </servlet>
               <servlet-mapping>
                   <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
                   <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
                   <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
               </servlet-mapping>
               <!-- **************************************************** -->
               <!-- CDI API initialization (Google Guice Implementation). -->
               <!-- **************************************************** -->
               <filter>
                   <filter-name>GuiceFilter</filter-name>
                   <filter-class>com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter</filter-class>
               </filter>
               <filter-mapping>
                   <filter-name>GuiceFilter</filter-name>
                   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
               </filter-mapping>
               <listener>
                   <listener-class>cdi.listener.GuiceListener</listener-class>
               </listener>
               <!-- **************************************************** -->

               <!-- ***** Specify session timeout of thirty (30) minutes. ***** -->
               <session-config>
                   <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
               </session-config>

               <welcome-file-list>
                   <welcome-file>index.jsf</welcome-file>
                   <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
               </welcome-file-list>
           </web-app>
   ```
2. Faces-config.xml

   ```
           <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
           <faces-config xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
               version="2.2">

               <!-- a hack to enfore session serialization -->
               <lifecycle>
                   <phase-listener>listener.SessionPhaseListener</phase-listener>
               </lifecycle>

           </faces-config>
   ```
3. SessionPhaseListener.java

   ```
           package listener;

           import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
           import javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent;
           import javax.faces.event.PhaseId;
           import javax.faces.event.PhaseListener;

           public class SessionPhaseListener implements PhaseListener {

               /** Used in object serialization */
               private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

               @Override
               public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent event) {
                   FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("CURRENT_TIME",
                           System.currentTimeMillis());
               }

               @Override
               public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent event) {
               }

               @Override
               public PhaseId getPhaseId() {
                   return PhaseId.ANY_PHASE;
               }
           }
   ```
4. InjectionProvider.java

   ```
           package cdi;

           import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

           import com.cloud.brochureforce.client.cdi.listener.GuiceListener;
           import com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderException;
           import com.sun.faces.vendor.WebContainerInjectionProvider;

           public class InjectionProvider extends WebContainerInjectionProvider {
               @Override
               public void inject(Object managedBean) throws InjectionProviderException {
                   if (isToBeInjectedByGuice(managedBean))
                       GuiceListener.injectMembers(managedBean);
               }

               /**
                * As an arbitrary choice, the choice here is to inject only into
                * {@code @ManagedBean} instances, so that other classes - not written by us
                * - wouldn't be injected too. This choice could be altered.
                * 
                * @param managedBean A JSF bean instance (annotated with @ManagedBean).
                * @return
                */
               private boolean isToBeInjectedByGuice(Object managedBean) {
                   return managedBean.getClass().getAnnotation(ManagedBean.class) != null;
               }

               @Override
               public void invokePostConstruct(Object managedBean) throws InjectionProviderException {
                   // @PostConstruct is already handled in classes we injected
                   if (!isToBeInjectedByGuice(managedBean))
                       super.invokePostConstruct(managedBean);
               }

               @Override
               public void invokePreDestroy(Object managedBean) throws InjectionProviderException {
                   super.invokePreDestroy(managedBean);
               }
           }
   ```
5. GuiceListener.java

   ```
           package cdi.listener;

           import cdi.JSFModule;
           import com.google.inject.AbstractModule;
           import com.google.inject.Guice;
           import com.google.inject.Injector;
           import com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceServletContextListener;

           public class GuiceListener extends GuiceServletContextListener {
               protected AbstractModule module;
               protected static Injector injector;

               public GuiceListener() {
                   module = new JSFModule();
                   if (injector == null) {
                       injector = Guice.createInjector(module);
                   }
               }

               @Override
               public Injector getInjector() {
                   return injector;
               }

               /**
                * given a class, generates an injected instance. Useful when an API call is
                * needed internally.
                */
               public static <T> T getInstance(Class<T> type) {
                   return injector.getInstance(type);
               }

               /**
                * given an injectable instance, injects its dependencies
                */
               public static void injectMembers(Object instance) {
                   injector.injectMembers(instance);
               }
           }
   ```
6. PostConstructTypeListener.java (A listener to handle @PostConstruct annotated code)

   ```
           package cdi.listener;

           import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
           import java.lang.reflect.Method;

           import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

           import com.google.inject.TypeLiteral;
           import com.google.inject.spi.InjectionListener;
           import com.google.inject.spi.TypeEncounter;
           import com.google.inject.spi.TypeListener;

           /**
            * Listener to detect @PostConstruct annotated code.
            */
           public class PostConstructTypeListener implements TypeListener {
               private final String packagePrefix;

               public PostConstructTypeListener(String packagePrefix) {
                   this.packagePrefix = packagePrefix;
               }

               @Override
               public <I> void hear(final TypeLiteral<I> typeLiteral, TypeEncounter<I> typeEncounter) {
                   Class<? super I> clz = typeLiteral.getRawType();
                   if (packagePrefix != null && !clz.getName().startsWith(packagePrefix))
                       return;

                   final Method method = getPostConstructMethod(clz);
                   if (method != null) {
                       typeEncounter.register(new InjectionListener<I>() {
                           @Override
                           public void afterInjection(Object i) {
                               try {
                                   // call the @PostConstruct annotated method after all
                                   // dependencies have been injected
                                   method.invoke(i);
                               } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException e) {
                                   throw new RuntimeException(e);
                               }
                           }
                       });
                   }
               }

               /**
                * checks whether the provided class, or one of its super-classes, has a
                * method with the {@code PostConstruct} annotation. the method may be
                * public, protected, package-private or private. if it's inaccessible by
                * Java rules, this method will also make it accessible before returning it.
                * 
                * @return the method that meets all requirements, or null if none found
                */
               private Method getPostConstructMethod(Class<?> clz) {
                   for (Method method : clz.getDeclaredMethods()) {
                       if (method.getAnnotation(PostConstruct.class) != null && isPostConstructEligible(method)) {
                           method.setAccessible(true);
                           return method;
                       }
                   }
                   Class<?> superClz = clz.getSuperclass();
                   return (superClz == Object.class || superClz == null) ? null : getPostConstructMethod(superClz);
               }

               /**
                * apply restrictions as defined in the <a href=
                * "http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html">JavaEE
                * specifications</a>
                */
               private boolean isPostConstructEligible(final Method method) {
                   return (method.getReturnType() == void.class) && (method.getParameterTypes().length == 0)
                           && (method.getExceptionTypes().length == 0);
               }
           }
   ```

and finally, the `ServletModule` required by Guice to create the injector:

```
            package cdi;

            import com.cloud.brochureforce.client.cdi.listener.PostConstructTypeListener;
            import com.google.inject.matcher.Matchers;
            import com.google.inject.servlet.ServletModule;

            public class JSFModule extends ServletModule {
                @Override
                protected void configureServlets() {
                    // add support for the @PostConstruct annotation for Guice-injected
                    // objects
                    // if you choose to remove it, also modify
                    // GuiceJsfInjector.invokePostConstruct()
                    bindListener(Matchers.any(), new PostConstructTypeListener(null));
                }

                protected String getServingUrl() {
                    return "*.jsf";
                }
            }
```

Now, I tried out the CDI implementation with this simple test:

Two `@javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped` managed beans:

1. CDIExampleBean.java

   ```
           package jsf.bean;

           import java.io.Serializable;
           import java.util.logging.Logger;

           import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
           import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
           import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
           import javax.inject.Inject;

           @ManagedBean(name = "jsfbCdi", eager = true)
           @SessionScoped
           public class CDIExampleBean implements Serializable {
               private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

               private String injectedProperty;

               @PostConstruct
               private void init() {
                   System.out.println("CDIExampleBean - Injection works!"); // It works.
               }

               /**
                * @return the injected property
                */
               public String setInjectedProperty() {
                   return injectedProperty;
               }

               /**
                * @param injectedProperty
                *            the new injectedProperty
                */
               public void setInjectedProperty(String injectedProperty) {
                   this.injectedProperty = injectedProperty;
               }
           }
   ```
2. ExampleBean.java

   ```
           package jsf.bean;

           import java.io.Serializable;
           import java.util.ArrayList;
           import java.util.Date;
           import java.util.List;

           import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
           import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
           import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
           import javax.inject.Inject;

           import com.cloud.brochureforce.dataaccess.PersistenceManager;
           import com.cloud.brochureforce.dataaccess.Queries;
           import com.cloud.brochureforce.dataaccess.entity.Visit;

           @ManagedBean(name="jsfbExample", eager=true)
           @SessionScoped
           public class ExampleBean implements Serializable {

               private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

               @Inject
               private CDIExampleBean jsfbCdi;

               @PostConstruct
               private void init() {
                   System.out.println("ExampleBean - Injection works!"); // It works.
               }

               /**
                * Method to test EL engine processing with parameters. 
                * @param param
                * @return
                */
               public void injectValue() {
                   this.jsfbCdi.setInjectedProperty("Injecting...");
               }
           }
   ```

`@Inject private CDIExampleBean jsfbCdi;` gets injected, yet it's destroyed when the method `injectValue()` ends.

How do I know that? If I invoke this property in index.xhtml by using AJAX like this:

```
            <ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
                template="WEB-INF/template/main.xhtml">
                <ui:define name="header">
                    <p style="text-align: center">HI ALL!</p>
                    <br />
                    <p style="text-align: center">JSF 2.2.4 is up and running on Google
                        App. Engine.</p>
                </ui:define>

                <ui:define name="content">
                    <h:outputLabel for="companyId" value="Company ID" />
                    <h:inputText id="companyId" value="" required=""
                        requiredMessage="This value is mandatory" />
                </ui:define>

                <ui:define name="footer">
                    <h:form>
                        <h:commandButton value="Inject!"
                            actionListener="#{jsfbExample.injectValue()}">
                            <f:ajax execute="@this" render="emptyText" />
                        </h:commandButton>
                        <h:commandButton value="Show injected!"
                            actionListener="#{jsfbCdi.getInjectedProperty()}">
                            <f:ajax execute="@this" render="injectedValue" />
                        </h:commandButton>
                        <h:outputText id="injectedValue" /><br/>
                        <h:outputText id="emptyText" value="" /><br/>
                    </h:form>
                </ui:define>
            </ui:composition>
```

and set a breakpoint in the `getInjectedProperty()` method, the associated field `private String injectedProperty;` returns `null`. This is what I mean when I say that JSF beans can't "interact" at all.

Could anybody here point me in the right direction? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that guice is implementing cdi, and actually respects annotations like @SessionScoped?

Comment: `CDI 1.0 with Google Guice 3.0` - Guice is **not** CDI (JSR-299 - **context** and dependency injection) implementation. Instead it is only JSR-300 (dependency injection) implementation. To put it simply, it works with `@Inject`, but has nothing to do with contexts.

Comment: Why the mix of JSF and CDI annotations?

Comment: On the other hand, I'm not an expert about those standards, @Siliarus. By "has nothing to do with contexts" you mean Guice can't distinguish between (or even worse, doesn't implement at all) javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped, javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped and other CDI scopes?

Comment: @Kukeltje , I used JSF annotations to be able to inject JSF bean instances into the EL expressions (`#{myBean.myProperty}`) with a customized injection provider and used Guice as DI provider to be able to define injection points in my JSF beans:

(`@Inject private CDIExampleBean jsfbCdi; // I can't do this without Guice. I already tried.`)

Comment: They have some scopes, but it is their own implementation, which "known nothing" of CDI scopes even if it might have the same name. Example is Guice [@RequestScoped](https://github.com/google/guice/blob/master/extensions/servlet/src/com/google/inject/servlet/RequestScoped.java) which is in no way linked to [CDI @RequestScoped](https://github.com/cdi-spec/cdi/blob/master/api/src/main/java/javax/enterprise/context/RequestScoped.java) .

Comment: UPDATE:
I've finally got the 3 features to run on GAE together. I made these corrections (in 2 comments because of space):

1. I added `<load-on-startup>` property to `FacesServlet` and set it to "0" (eager loading, as far as I know)
2. I removed the FacesServlet `<servlet-mapping>`s leaving the `<servlet>` declaration only, so the FacesFactory is initialized by the `ConfigureListener` but JSF requests are served through Guice using a FacesHttpServlet wrapper with an injected FacesServlet instance in the constructor.

Comment: 3. I declared the `com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener` (in charge of JSF initialization) BEFORE Guice initialization.
4. I´m not trying to inject a bean instance directly in another one anymore. Instead, I inject business logic class singleton instance (like an EJB) bound in the JSFModule class.